# When are endomorphism rings Dedekind-finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

**The Question**

Is it possible to characterise the abelian groups $G$ whose endomorphism rings are Dedekind-finite? Or, at least, are there conditions which are necessary/sufficient for this to occur?

(A ring $R$ is said to be Dedekind-finite if $ab=1\implies ba=1$.)

---

**Some Motivation**

In algebraic structures such as groups and rings, the inverse of a homomomorphism $f:A\to B$, if it exists, is also a homomorphism. This leads to the rather convenient fact that a bijective homomorphism is automatically an isomorphism. Unfortunately, the situation with injective homomorphisms is not so nice: if $f:A\to B$ is an injective homomorphism, then it is not necessarily the case that a left inverse of $f$ is also a homomorphism; likewise, a right inverse of a surjective homomorphism is not necessarily a homomorphism.

These considerations led me to the following question. Suppose $G$ is an abelian group, and $R$ is its endomorphism ring. If $R$ is *not* Dedekind-finite, then there exist $f,g\in R$ such that $f\circ g=\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}\id$ but $g\circ f\neq\id$. The map $g$ has the following properties: it is an injective, but not surjective, homomorphism, and it has a left inverse $f$ which is also a homomorphism. This situation can occur for some rings, e.g. in the case that $G=\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ with pointwise addition, but not for others, e.g. $G=\mathbb Z$ with the usual addition. In the latter case, every injective endomorphism which is not surjective, such as $f(n)=2n$, does not have a left inverse which is also an endomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is one elementary set of equivalents:

1. $End(M_R)$ is Dedekind finite
2. If $M\oplus N\cong M$ then $N=\{0\}$.

A very closely related condition is: an $R$ module $M$ is called Hopfian if every onto endomorphism of $M$ is an isomorphism.  (An Abelian [Hopfian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfian_group) is just a Hopfian $\mathbb Z$ module) It turns out this is sufficient for $End(M_R)$ to be Dedekind finite but it is not equivalent in general.